# node async and http multiple post requests

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach, http-post, async.js

```
async.forEachOf([some ids], function (value, key, callback) {
let post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '5000',
    path: '/predictans',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

let post_data = {
    //some data using the value
};

let post_req = http.request(post_options, function (resp) {
    resp.on('data', (ans) => {

        //save the answer

        //do the second POST request
        callback();
    });
});

post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();

}, function (err) {
    console.log('some error');
});
```

I want to send multiple POST requests to the same server. I want to first, get the response from the first request and then send the next one, and so on. 
However, my code sends all requests at once. What mistakes am I making?

Answer (score 0):

A Request is completed when "end" event is triggered.
Replace "data" with "end" event.

```
resp.on("end",()=>{callback()});
```